# Console application string was not recognised as valid datetime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I have a excel sheet in which am taking a date column in this format `"23/8/11 01:33:01:PM"`
and am inserting it in sql 2008 using datarow but am getting a error

> String was not recognised as valid datetime.

Can any one please help?

```
DateTime newdate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[8].ToString());
```

Answer (score 7):

Here how [`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) method looks like when you decompile it;

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(string value)
{
  if (value == null)
    return new DateTime(0L);
  else
    return DateTime.Parse(value, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

As you can see, this method use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) method with your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx). And if your string doesn't match your current culture date format, your code will be broken. That's the reason you get this error.

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) with `"dd/M/yy hh:mm:ss:tt"` format instead.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

```
string s = "23/8/11 01:33:01:PM";
DateTime newdate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/M/yy hh:mm:ss:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(newdate);
```

Output will be;

```
8/23/2011 1:33:01 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/TF4iMm)</kbd>.

For your case;

```
DateTime newdate = DateTime.ParseExact(row[8].ToString(), "dd/M/yy hh:mm:ss:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more informations, take a look;

- [**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: As much as this is a solution to the problem, it doesn't really explain why the OP's code doesn't work which I feel is just as important as a solution because the OP can learn from it.

Comment: @James You are right. At first, I didn't want to write it because your explanation looks fully enough. Just I didn't want to write same things `:)` But updated now..

Comment: Soner. your code works fine but it gives error when inserting in sql "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
The statement has been terminated." the columns in sql are datetime

Comment: @user2795254 Sounds like you had a format issue again but now against to _SQL Server_. Take a look [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: @Soner i want to insert the value "23-08-2011 01:33:01" into sql but in sql the format is "2011-08-23 10:20:48.000". is there a way to insert it in sql?

Comment: @user2795254 Maybe.. Take a look also http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx which I believe you can find the solution `:)`

Comment: @Soner this was not helpful :( my query is am reading values from excel storing in datarow and with datarow am inserting to SQL. but stuck when date columns comes. from excel by ur query m getting the date in "23-08-2011 01:33:01" but in sql the values are like this "2011-08-22 10:21:18.000" is there a way i can convert in c# not sql the date in "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00:000" ? i want to convert "23-08-2011 01:33:01" --> "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00:000"

Comment: @user2795254 your question makes **no reference whatsoever** to inserting the dates into an SQL database. Please ask another question if you have a problem in this area.

Answer (score 2):

[Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) internally calls [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) which by default will use the current culture of your application. If `23/8/11 01:33:01:PM` is not a valid format for this culture then this method will fail.

For specific date formats it's best to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) e.g.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23/8/11 01:33:01:PM", "dd/M/yy hh:mm:ss:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This approach makes your code *culture independent* which means the date will always be parsed correctly (given it's in the specified format).

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
DateTime newdate = Convert.ToDateTime("8/23/11 01:33:01 PM");
```

I changed day and month and removed the colon a the end. But that is very specific. You need to know more about the dates passed to do that.

Comment: This will work *given* it conforms to the current culture of the application - that's guess work at best. What happens if the culture of the machine running the app changes?

Comment: That is exactly what I said (or was trying to say).

Comment: Your making the assumption though that the OP is using a culture which supports that date format - which they could be. However, that means the application relies on the data being formatted accordingly - which might never be the case. When dealing with dates (at least from an external resource) it's generally a better idea to be strict and say "*this is exactly how the dates should come in*" and accommodate for that in your application i.e. make them culture independent.

Comment: @James Agreed! I would have it no other way. But I doubt that the person asking the question will make the necessary changes...

Comment: You can only provide the information to the OP - if they don't want to utilize it then that's their choice. However, you shouldn't provide sub-standard answers because you *don't think* the OP will take on board what you say.

Comment: when inserting the value "8/23/11 01:33:01 PM" in sql it throws an error conversion of  char type to datetime throws an exception